# UCWA: makeMeAvailable returning forbidden and API confusion

Tags: skype-for-business, ucwa

I'm trying to create a small console application sending and receiving message from SFB.
I started by using the code from https://github.com/tamhinsf/ucwa-sfbo-console and followed the readme.md for creating the app in the Azure Management Portal (I assigned all the delegated permissions just to be sure).
All already included API work (so I'm sure I'm logging in correctly), but when I try to invoke makeMeAvailable to receive IM call (looking at https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/KeyTasks-Communication-IncomingIMCall) I get the following response

```
{"code":"Forbidden","message":"The requested operation isn\u0027t allowed."}
```

My post data is the following

```
 {"SupportedModalities":["Messaging"]}
```

Which is just as the example from the ucwa.skype.com site.

I'm also finding problematic to send a message, on the skype site the https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/Resources-startMessaging shows a call to

```
Post https://fe1.contoso.com:443//v1/applications/970/communication/startMessaging
```

but on my application response embedded.communication._links.startMessaging is /messagingInvitations and not /startMessaging.
  The documentation on https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/KeyTasks-CreateApplication-3 also shows

```
"startMessaging":{"href":"/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/105/communication/messagingInvitations"},
```

I'm quite confused over what I should do to correctly send and receive messages and the API documentation did not really help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *makeMeAvailable* isn't supported yet in UCWA for Online. Probably when it'll be introduced, a new app permission will be added in AAD permissions, which will need to be granted. So, that's expected, but the documentation is indeed outdated and just referring to behavior for UCWA for On-Prem.
   See also / vote: [Enable 'me' resource and controlling self user's presence in UCWA](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/13695315-enable-me-resource-and-controlling-self-user-s-p)
2. You're correct, good finding. However, POSTing on the *messagingInvitations* resource (which is no where in documentation), is the correct way. So following the principle of using the URIs returned by operations, and not composing URIs by convention in your code is the way to go.
   You can notify this by creating an issue here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-docs/issues

Comment: "User.ReadWrite" is exposed for Skype for Business Online and "Allows the app to read and update presence, photo, location, note, call forwarding settings of the signed-in user".  My code example (referenced in the original post) makes use of makeMeAvailable to set user presence.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/skypeforbusinessonlinescopepermissions

Comment: I confirm this now works as expected: 'makeMeAvailable' now returns 204. I'm pretty sure it was't so a month ago, at the time of my answer, with the same permissions request and same code. Was this change tracked or announced somewhere?

Comment: It's been available for some time now - unfortunately, it looks like there wasn't any announcement made.  I can't recall when, but it's been way more than a month since I've updated my code to support presence.

Comment: cheers. well, you surely have more insights, but allow me to say it's quite a big issue the fact we wait for features to be enabled for years, and then they get enabled without notice. How can we plan building our solutions in this way..